# unable to upload a file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

whenever i try to upload a file by pressing 'upload file' after choosing, it directs me to a blank page.tried the official documentation as well as various videos on youtube.

```
 public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('upload_form');
}
  //upload_form
 <?php 
echo form_open_multipart(base_url()."index.php/home/upload_file");
echo form_upload("file");
echo form_submit("upload","Upload file");
?>
public function upload_file()
{
    if($this->input->post("upload")===false)
        return;

    $config['upload_path'] = "./uploads/";
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    //$config['max_width']  = '1024';
    //$config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload("file"))
    {
        $this->load->view("error");
        }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view("success");
    }
}
```

error and success pages are just simple texts.

Comment: you do not have a form field called "upload" so `if($this->input->post("file")===false)`

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: can you post you html?

Answer (score 0):

```
($this->input->post("upload")===false)
```

will not work. Use this instead:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['upload']['name'])) { 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Where do you get `upload` when the file field name is `file` ?